# Repeatedly multiplying the same two dataframes many times raises error after some iterations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

In the example below, after some iterations without a problem, a division error is raised because the `C` dataframe becomes filled up with 0s instead of ones (the number of iterations without a problem changes from time to time, e.g. 22 to 46 on Spider, 200 to 600 on Jupyter).

Lowering the number of rows or columns avoids the problem. Seems to point to a memory problem.

Any explanation would be welcome, as I'm performing multiple simulations requiring similar calculations (But I know the example does not make practical sense).

```
import pandas as pd
A=pd.DataFrame(1, range(1,1000), range(1,132))
B=A.copy()
for i in range (0,10000):
    C=A.multiply(B)
    print ("Iteration "+str(i)+", Sum of C : "+str(C.sum().sum())+", Inverse of the sum of C : "+str(1/(C.sum().sum())))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Python or Pandas problem.  If you run it raw from the terminal, you will see that this runs properly.

It's probably due to overhead of Spyder and Jupyter trying to capture data as the loop is progressing.

With a machine with enough RAM, you should still be able to run this on Spyder and/or Jupyter.  I just ran it on Jupyter using a 16GB machine and it ran fine.

Comment: You're probably right. I ran it too on another machine with 16GB without problem. Thanks!